# Android listview find by id nullpointer

Tags: android

ONCREATE I PUT

```
   ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
```

Below is the code i have my listview getting null pointer crashing app for some reason my listview from the code below is not finding please tell me what am doing

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            parsedHtmlNode.setText(htmlContentInStringFormat);
            String  input = amarrdatta;
            String  dayyz = dayys;
            dayyz = dayyz.replace(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            input = input.replace(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          //  textViewwww.setText(dayyz +" " +input);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            count++;
            temp=temp+count;
            HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
            temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, dayyz);
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, input);
            temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "22");
            temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Unmarried");
            list.add(temp);
            ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);  // getting nullpointer here listview

        }
    }
```

java null pointer still

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            parsedHtmlNode.setText(htmlContentInStringFormat);
            String  input = amarrdatta;
            String  dayyz = dayys;
            dayyz = dayyz.replace(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            input = input.replace(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          //  textViewwww.setText(dayyz +" " +input);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            count++;
            temp=temp+count;
            HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
            temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, dayyz);
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, input);
            temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "22");
            temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Unmarried");
            list.add(temp);
            ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Comment: Can you put your onCreate() code?

Comment: Post your layout xml as well.

Comment: i am not 100% sure, but i think you didnt make the ListView listview gobal. you can only "use" listview in `onCreate()` like you did it. Simply move  `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);` into `onPostExecute()` and that should fix it

Comment: when i move it to onpostexecute    stil give nuller

Comment: @JeanLee post layout xml, please

Comment: @JeanLee, the onPostExecute belongs to an AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialize `listView` variable.

You did `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);` in `onCreate()`. But with this code you redeclare `listView` variable, it hides global `listView`, and global `listView` remains null.

Remove type in `onCreate()`:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
```

or move complete line to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: when i add this on oncreate  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);      the faar left listview becomes red ?

Comment: @JeanLee it means you don't have global `listView` variable. Declare it or move the line with type to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: please check the code main post i edited stil probs ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the `ListView listView;` outside the onCreate:

```
 ListView listView;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    parsedHtmlNode.setText(htmlContentInStringFormat);
    String  input = amarrdatta;
    String  dayyz = dayys;
    dayyz = dayyz.replace(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    input = input.replace(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    //  textViewwww.setText(dayyz +" " +input);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    count++;
    temp=temp+count;
    HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, dayyz);
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, input);
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "22");
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Unmarried");
    list.add(temp);
    ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);  // getting nullpointer here listview
}
```

Comment: i have to say this is wiered , i have this code in mainactivity2 all working but now am shifting the code to mainactivity and its giving this prob ?

Comment: @JeanLee Are you sure you have view with id `listView3` in mainactivity layout?

Comment: YUP I HAVE IT i just dont understand why its messiing about

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML `ListView` id properly and then you need to use like below

**Fragment or other layout inflate**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutname, container, false);

ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView3);
```

**Activity**

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
```

Comment: when i add this on oncreate ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);    the 2nd listview text becomes light great meaning the listview onpostcreate did not take affect why

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not placed your AsyncTask inside your Activity class.Make sure your AsyncTask is an inner Class to your Activity